# .env does not recognize Turkish characters (Mojibake)

Tags: python, unicode, bots, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot for my server with Python and I am trying to set my token, special variables, etc.
So I set my variable in the .env file and called it. The message worked but it has a "Mojibake" problem that looks like this:

```
TheLast, Discord Sunucumuza HoÅŸgeldin. Burada Her tÃ¼rlÃ¼ Kaynak paylaÅŸÄ±mÄ±i Bilgi PaylaÅŸÄ±mÄ± Ve Beyin FÄ±rtÄ±nalarÄ± DÃ¶ndÃ¼rÃ¼yoruz HoÅŸgeldin !!!
```

But in the .env file it is declared as (It's in turkish if anyone wondered):

```
GREETING_MESSAGE = "Discord Sunucumuza Hoşgeldin. Burada Her türlü Kaynak paylaşımıi Bilgi Paylaşımı Ve Beyin Fırtınaları Döndürüyoruz Hoşgeldin !!!"
```

Can I make it recognize these characters? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The term for what you're seeing is [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), where text is encoded in one encoding but displayed in another.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for the information updated the post.

Comment: How did you read and display the file?  It is being read with the wrong encoding, but you've shown no code that we can correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises due to different [encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) when saving and reading the file. Generally if applicable, you should aim to [always encode text files with UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/). This requires you to use a text editor that allows specifying the encoding the file should be saved with. Most code editors and IDEs *do* allow this. Even with Window Notepad you can explicitly specify the Encoding in the `File` > `Save as...` dialog.

Alternatively, you can enter your non-ASCII characters in the string with a Unicode escape sequence `\uxxxx` where `xxxx` is the hexadecimal value of the character's unicode code point (e. g. `\u015f` for `ş`). You'd need to individually look up the code point per character, either just with google or tools like the windows character map.